# Can't open Inkscape file in Adobe Illustrator CS 3

Tags: fonts, adobe-illustrator, inkscape

I have an Inkscape file that I need to open in Illustrator but it won't work.

I tried to save the Inkscape file as .svg but when I open it up in Illustrator I get

> "bitstream vera sans: a unknown error
>   has occurred"
>
> "the document "document.svg" uses
>   fonts or characters which are not
>   available or are in a different format
>   that originally specified."

Comment: This isnt really programming related, it is computer related so perhaps it should be moved to superuser

Comment: This should be migrated to super user

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can download the font [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/GNOME/sources/ttf-bitstream-vera/1.10/).

Answer (score 1):

Bitstream Vera Sans is a free font, you should be able to download a copy if you don't have it installed on your computer.

Answer (score 1):

If installing the font does not produce identical results (often the case when switching between vector editors), you can convert text to path. Select your text in Inkscape and do

> Path -> Object to path

or <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>shift</kbd><kbd>c</kbd>

Note that this means you can no longer edit the text; it behaves as a graphic.